# How to extract in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to extract the word followed by `location_name` from an example:
{'type': ['city_group'], 'location_name': ['Costa Del Sol'], 'cities_groups_ids': ['3'], 'bedrooms': ['1:']}

I would like to create column called "location" where I find "Costa Del Sol"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [json_value_array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value_array):

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(
    "{'type': ['city_group'], 'location_name': ['Costa Del Sol'], 'cities_groups_ids': ['3'], 'bedrooms': ['1:']}",
    "$.location_name"
) AS locations_array;
```

Add `[OFFSET(0)]` if you need only the first value from the `location_name` list:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(
    "{'type': ['city_group'], 'location_name': ['Costa Del Sol'], 'cities_groups_ids': ['3'], 'bedrooms': ['1:']}",
    "$.location_name"
)[OFFSET(0)] AS location;
```